# Remove duplicated values with filter n_distinct in dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr

I have the following data:

```
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)

per_id <- c(11, 12, 12, 13, 13, 13)
house_id <- c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 4)
individual <- c('John Doe','Peter Gynn', 'Peter Gynn', 'Jolie Hope', 'Jolie Hope', 'Jolie Hope')
first_obs <- c(1920, 1920, 1925, 1920, 1925, 1926)
last_obs <- c(1925, 1925, 1925, 1925, 1926, 1927)
moved_in <- c(1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1)
address <- c('king street', 'market street', 'oxford street', 'montgomery road', 'princes ave', 'montgomery road' )

df <- data.frame(per_id, house_id, individual, address, first_obs, last_obs, moved_in)

df <- mutate(df, id = rownames(df))
```

Now I want to transform the data to yearly observations. I am using the following code for this:

```
df$year <- mapply(seq,df$first_obs,df$last_obs,SIMPLIFY=FALSE)

new_df <- df %>% 
  unnest(year) %>% 
  select(-first_obs,-last_obs)
```

In the next step, I want to remove all duplicated years, since I only want one observation per person in a year. If someone moved in and out between different addresses in the same year, I only want to keep the observation of the address that he or she moved in to on a given year. Not the observation of the last year he or she remained on the previous address.

I've tried this code, but it doesn't remove any duplicated values.

```
new_df <- new_df %>%
  group_by(id) %>% 
  filter(n_distinct(year)==n()| row_number()==2)
```

I can't really figure out what's wrong here.

Comment: Your example throws error: `Error in data.frame(per_id, house_id, individual, changed_occupation,  : 
  object 'changed_occupation' not found
`

Comment: Instead of recreating the data (especially given the missing columns noted ^^), could you just give us `dput(new_df)`, since that will get straight to the part where you're having an issue?

Comment: please edit your post in order to reproduce your error

Comment: There are no records in your data that have duplicated id and year in combination. The following returns FALSE: `with(new_df, any(duplicated(cbind(id, year))))`. Did you want to group by individual?

Comment: Sorry about that guys, it should work fine now. @Edward, yes I only want one observation per year and individual. It would make sense to group by per_id, but that returns a result with 8 observations.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `pivot_wider` to remove duplicate entries (per individual and year) by taking just the last address, and then just go back to long format with `pivot_longer` dropping NA rows.

```
resul <- new_df %>%
  pivot_wider(id_cols = individual,
              names_from = year,
              values_from = address,
              #Apply this function where more than 1 element matches each entry in the wide format.
              values_fn = list(address = function(x) unique(x)[length(unique(x))])) %>%
  pivot_longer(cols = -individual,
               names_to = "year",
               values_to = "address",
               values_drop_na = T)
```

Comment: Thank you @Jonathan, this could be an option.